# IE11 Form Templating, innerHTML & outerHTML issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I made a big form and I need a little templating to get it to work.
Like so

[image: Before]

[image: After]

So I want to have an HTML DIV in my HTML code with the **id="sponsor_template"**, read it and add it to the button.
Here is my js-code

```
var sponsorBTN = document.querySelector('[name="sponsors_add"]');
if (sponsorBTN !== null) {
    sponsorBTN.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var s_template = document.querySelector('[id="sponsor_template"]');
        sponsorBTN.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', s_template.outerHTML.replace('id="sponsor_template"', 'name="sponsor"')
                                                               .replace('display:none', ''))
    })
}
```

It works perfectly on any browser except for IE.
The only thing I know, where the issue could be is innerHTML / outerHTML because my output is incomplete when I console.log them in IE.
So it just cuts off after the 7'th line of HTML.

Here is the JSFiddle to this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/tdxkiller/b5m0t7xm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
s_template.outerHTML.replace('id="sponsor_template"', 'name="sponsor"').replace('display:none', '')
```

I'm not sure why it has a problem with "`display:none`"; I think there's some problem with the ":" character. However, I changed it to the below and it worked:

```
s_template.outerHTML.replace('id="sponsor_template"', 'name="sponsor"').replace('none', 'block')
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about it and found out that even if the console.log() of the whole outerHTML doesnt show up correctly in IE11, it would still show something. After investigating further I found out that IE11 converts `display:none` to `display: none;` so that was the issue after all.